# How to implement Cycle Walking Method of FPE to get length of output encrypted string same as input string length?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric, javax.crypto

As per Cycle Walking Method concept in Format Preserving Encryption (FPE) as follows
Say M is our desired output length of String, X is Plain Text

```
AES(X)=Y
if (Y>M) {
    AES(X)
}
```

We do this cycle until we get desired output length. But when I tried doing this by writing a loop on top of AES Encryption code, the output length of encrypted string is increasing each time. What am I missing?

```
main()
{
    String strToEncrypt = "012345678";
    final String strPssword = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGH";
    AES.setKey(strPssword);

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
          AES.encrypt(strToEncrypt.trim());
          System.out.println("String to Encrypt: " + strToEncrypt); 
          System.out.println("Encrypted: " + AES.getEncryptedString());
          strToEncrypt = AES.getEncryptedString();
        }
}
```

The result I got is

```
String to Encrypt: 012345678
Encrypted: /a+WAzyVsLRkWXtQu1RFrw==

String to Encrypt: /a+WAzyVsLRkWXtQu1RFrw==
Encrypted: K2DVyvglFSGncoTvl7al00cPzKdRyGkW/YTOTqXp3sk=

String to Encrypt: K2DVyvglFSGncoTvl7al00cPzKdRyGkW/YTOTqXp3sk=
Encrypted: I7CBulv5XdEaSX55wFlXFHgtmwFZO6GZvmZ+OrH8jSRSga7NhdG6bYXEwR90YzSI
```

But what I am trying for is after some number of iterations, the output encrypted string length should be equal to length of input string "012345678"

Comment: First, the increase of size is likely due to a padding scheme. Your question does not specify which library is used for AES encryption, but it could be that the library uses some padding scheme by default, which prepends meta-data for each encryption. Please edit your answer to specify what library is used for AES.

Comment: Second, there seems to be a misunderstanding about the cycle-walking method (as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption#FPE_from_cycle_walking)). Applying AES encryption will never decrease the size of your data (it does not perform compression). For cycle-walking the idea is to apply AES until enough of the upper bits become zeros, such that cutting of those zeros gives you a result of the desired length. Your code does not currently implement such a cutting mechanism.